# Properties of ZFS ZVOL

Tags: zfs, block-device

I'm starting to teach myself how ZFS works - so I may have fundamental misunderstandings here - if so, please let me know.

Is a ZVOL a block device, or does it simply behave in a manor similar to a block device ?

I can resize a ZVOL using a command like

```
zfs set volsize=SIZE poolname/volname
```

Does the above behave the same way as an LVM volume would, ie

1. Can I expand the ZVOL I then expand the partitions/filesystems in the VM associated with the ZVOL.
2. **Can I safely REDUCE the size of the ZVOL after shrinking the partititions/
   filesystems in the ZVOL**  (This is the operation I am most concerned about)
3. Can I map the ZVOL to a loopback device using losetup and play with it the same way I might play with an LVM block device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as if it was a block device.

1. Yes, you first increase the zvol, then grow the file system inside it to the new size (similar to increasing the size of an existing partition on a traditional hard disk). Of course, your file system must support regrowing (here is an [example with GParted](https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Resizing+Linux+VM+Disks))
2. This depends again on the contained file system and your data (see last paragraph of linked resource):

   > Decrease the disk size is almost the same as increasing it. The only difference is that you need to resize your paritions before you reduce the zfs volsize.
3. I don't know how LVM volumes differ here to normal block devices - assume your zvol is like an ordinary partition presented as a disk.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. It all makes perfect sense. Yes, LVMs also appear as a normal block devices. (My concern is it might be different because I see I can compress the zvol and also snapshots work differently - and I didn't want to build a solution on a platform requiring functionality I don't adequately understand. Thanks again